# Windows 10 NSIS script Version string Manipulation

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to get my NSIS installer needs to set the items below. However, the version number must be in the format X.X.X.X (no dashes are allowed). My version number is currently being passed to me in the form X.X.X-rXXXX, How would I have nsis convert the version number in the form X.X.X-rXXXX to the form X.X.X.X required by nsis?

```
VIProductVersion "3.6.0.rXXXXX" 
VIAddVersionKey "ProductName?" "Witchcraft" 
VIAddVersionKey "CompanyName?" "Witchcraft, LLC" 
VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright?" "Copyright (c) 2015 Witchcraft, LLC" 
VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription?" "Witchcraft" 
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion?" "3.6.0.0" 
VIAddVersionKey "ProductVersion?" "3.6.0.0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'll explain where the X.X.X.X restriction comes from. The `VIProductVersion` attribute sets the version number in the [VS_FIXEDFILEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997(v=vs.85).aspx) block in the version information resource and it has to be 4 16-bit numbers.

`VIAddVersionKey` adds a string and the name and value can be whatever you want but there are some names defined by Microsoft that you probably want to include (They are listed in the NSIS help file).

You can use the `!searchreplace` and `!searchparse` preprocessor instructions to modify strings at compile time:

```
!define VERSION "3.6.0-r12345" # This could be passed in with 'makensis /DVERSION=3.6.0-r12345 setup.nsi' etc

!searchreplace /ignorecase VERSION_NUMBERSONLY "${VERSION}" "r" ""
!searchreplace /ignorecase VERSION_NUMBERSONLY "${VERSION_NUMBERSONLY}" "-" "."

VIProductVersion "${VERSION_NUMBERSONLY}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion" "${VERSION}" 
VIAddVersionKey "ProductVersion" "${VERSION}"
```